# https Get request failing on first try - python request

Tags: python, python-requests, httpcookie

While executing a GET request on api.nasdaq.com, I am getting error response 400 - The request has an invalid header name.
But If I hit the same URL in a browser, it does return a valid response.

Also AFTER hitting the url via browser, below code then works fine. If I use a new value for symbol variable then again it fails with 400 . Each time once I try the url in browser and then run this code it works but not first time.

Is this behavior due to any cookie usage? Any help is appreciated.

```
import requests

symbol = 'ALB'
url = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/{}/historical?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=2021-07-06&todate=2021-07-07".format(symbol)
headers = {
                "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "Connection":"keep-alive",
                "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36",
                "cache - control":"max-age=0, no-cache, no-store",
                "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
    }
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, verify=True)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print("download response code:{}".format(response.status_code))
    print("download response text:{}".format(response.text))
else:
    print(response.text)
```

Failure response:

```
download response code:400
download response text:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

various symbols that can used to test this is AMZN, AAPL, MSFT, ALB, ABC, SQ

Comment: Comment out the User-Agent and tell me if it works or not

Answer (score 1):

Using these headers get me a 200 response. I capitalized the cache control and upgrade insecure request.

I can't help you with the cookie usage question unfortunately.

```
headers = {
                "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "Connection":"keep-alive",
                "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36",
                "Cache-Control":"max-age=0, no-cache, no-store",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
    }
```

Comment: @MadhaviD np, can you mark it as final aswer?